# Passing the output of a command to another in one line

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, command, arguments

I want to take a screenshot with `import`, and save it into a file whose name is current time.

Here is what I've tried:

```
sunqingyao:~$ date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png'
screenshot-170716-173336.png
# OK

sunqingyao:~$ import screenshot-170716-173336.png
sunqingyao:~$ ls -l screenshot-170716-173336.png 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sunqingyao sunqingyao 250556 Jul 16 17:35 screenshot-170716-173336.png
# OK

sunqingyao:~$ date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png' | import
import: missing an image filename `import' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1293.
# Not OK
```

For some reason, I want this command to be a one-liner.

**Background info:**

Actually I'm trying to bind a key to screenshot taking with i3. Here is the relevant part of my `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
# Take a screenshot upon pressing $mod+x (select an area)
# https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings
bindsym --release $mod+x exec --no-startup-id date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png' | import
```

Seems that I can only bind a key to a command that can fit in only one line, which is why a one-liner is required.

Comment: Use command substitution: `import $(date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png' )` and `bindsym --release $mod+x exec --no-startup-id import $(date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png')`.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Seems that it's not done _in one line_ in the question you linked to :/

Comment: Technically it is, as jimmij stated use $() , which is command substitution form

Comment: Or use pipe then xargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use command-substitution as the other answer suggests, or use `xargs` to use what  pipe gives:

```
$ date '+screenshot-%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png' | xargs -I {} import  {}                                                              

$ ls screenshot-*                                                                                                            
screenshot-170716-042853.png
```

Answer (score 1):

since `import` will take the name of the `.png` as argument constract it and call the `import`.
Think that first wil the `$()` will be substitute and then will be passed as argument in `import`

```
import $(date +'screenshot-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.png')
```

e.g with `set -xv` & `echo` enable

```
$ echo $(date +'screenshot-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.png')
echo $(date +'screenshot-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.png')
++ date +screenshot-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.png
+ echo screenshot-20170716-131720.png
screenshot-20170716-131720.png
```